# Spring Schedule expression configure externally

Tags: spring, schedule

I use a Spring Schedule in my application. Now I will configure the cron expression externally. This one at the bottom does not work. Has anyone an idee how to do this?

```
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties(locations = "classpath:application.properties", ignoreUnknownFields = true, prefix = "myProject.prefix")
public class MyClass{

@Scheduled(cron = "${myProperty}")
public void myMethod() {
```

Comment: Am I correct in assuming the expression / class works if you do not use a property?

Comment: Yes, it works fine with **@Scheduled(cron = "*/5 * * * * ?")**

Answer (score 1):

Have you [activated](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-enable-annotation-support) scheduling in your configuration?

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class AppConfig {

    [...]

}
```